# React. Map thru this.state.data.response[0] to return it as component with props

Tags: reactjs, api, frontend

Trying to call component with props from state but getting error:

> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'this.state.data.response[0].map')…

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";

export default class AllMenuItems extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            data: {
                response: [],
            },
        };
        this.getItems();
        this.listItems();
    }

    backend_server = "http://localhost:5000/allitems_detailed";

    getItems() {
        fetch(this.backend_server)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => this.setState({ data: { response: data } }))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("AllMenuItems getItems() fetch error", error);
            });
            // returns array: 
            // 0 [name1, name2, …, nameN]
            // 1 [desc1, desc2, …, descN]
            // 2 [url1, url2, …, urlN]          
    }

    listItems() {

         return this.state.data.response[0].map((item_name, count) => {
              return <MenuItem item_name={item_name} 
                               item_description={this.state.data.response[1][count]}
                               item_link={this.state.data.response[2][count]}
                     />
             }
             );
         };
    }

    render() {
         return <div>{this.listItems()}</div>;
    }
}
```

*In the future I will use axios, but for now I really want to do it with "fetch" for learning*

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.data.response[0]` is throwing that error. You are initializing your state with empty an array. So when your component mounts for the first time, it's still empty and you can't access any elements from the empty array.

You can add a null check before rendering or optional chaining.

```
listItems() {
const { data } = this.state;
return data.response.length > 0 && data.response[0].map((item_name, count) => {
    return <MenuItem item_name={item_name} 
            item_description={this.state.data.response[1][count]}
            item_link={this.state.data.response[2][count]}
    />
    });
};

/// or 
return this.state.data.response?.[0]?.map
```

or simple you can do like this.

```
render() {
         return <div>{this.state.data.response?.length > 0 && this.listItems()}</div>
    }
```